# Почему оптимизатор запросов может не использовать SEEK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Допустим, есть 2 таблицы, которые нужно соединить между собой в которых очень очень много данных.
Первая таблицы присоединятся ко второй , где столбец второй таблицы- это кластеризованный индекс, а так же выполняется фильтрация по дате по колонке первой таблицы.

Так вот, оптимизатор запросов выбирает сканирование индекса второй таблицы вместо поиска в индексе.

Что могло повлиять на его решением, кроме устаревшей статистики? Вроде, при большом числе записей выгоднее искать, чем просматривать.

**UPD**

На самом деле пример малость упростил и по факту там 3 таблицы.

Как-то вот так по факту выглядит запрос и план.(Я его анонимизировал)

```
select 
            Object1.Column1,
            Object2.Column2,
            Object2.Column3, 
            Object1.Column4, 
            Object1.Column5, 
            Object3.Column6,
            Object2.Column7,
            Object1.Column8
            from Object4 Object5 with(nolock)
        join Object6 Object2 with(nolock)   on Object2.Column9 = Object5.Column9
        join Object7 Object1 with(nolock)           on Object1.Column2 = Object2.Column2
        join Object8 Object9 with(nolock)   on Object9.Column10 = Object1.Column10
        join Object10 Object3 with(nolock)      on Object3.Column6 = Object9.Column6
    
    
    where 
        Object5.Column11 >= Variable1 and 
        Object5.Column11 < Variable2
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот не могу понять, почему он сканирует нижнюю левую таблицу, а не ищет там...
P.S И порядок какой-то странный. Как я понимаю, сначала 2 таблицы соединяются целиком между собой без каких-либо условий, а потом в самом конце делается результирующий джойн, где уже есть фильтрация по дате.

Comment: Существует индекс на дате?

Comment: @SergeyMoiseenko, нет.

Comment: Вот здесь рассматривается похожий случай, когда при определенных условиях seek оказывается более дорогим, чем scan. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833661/why-does-this-sql-result-in-index-scan-instead-of-an-index-seek

Comment: @matrix, Я обновил вопрос.

Comment: какой именно скан вас смущает? object7.index4?

Comment: оптимизатор предсказал, что значительное количество записей из object7.index4 попадет под результат. у него была альтернатива - сделать 200к seek-ов (с непредсказуемым рандомным обращением к таблице), или один скан с линейным чтением всей таблицы. он выбрал скан, как более дешевый по io

Comment: на самом деле у вас проблема в key lookup (который 80% красный) - но что его вызывает - тяжело сказать без xml-ного плана (реального, а не estimated)